# Writing a File using FileOutput Stream

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream

```
import java.io.*;
class CopyFile 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
            throws IOException
    {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin=null;
        FileOutputStream fout=null;

        if(args.length!=2)
        {
            System.out.println("Mention the name of Source and Destination File");
            return;
        }
        try{
            fin=new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            fout=new FileOutputStream(args[1]);

            do{
                i=fin.read();
                if(i!=-1) fout.write(i);

            }while(i!=1);

        } catch (IOException exc)
        {System.out.println("I/O Error Exception exc"+exc);
        }
        finally {
            try{
                if(fin !=null) fin.close();

            }catch (IOException exc){
                System.out.println("Error Closing the File");}

            try {
                if(fout !=null) fout.close();

            }catch (IOException exc)
            {System.out.println("Error Closing the File");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Above Coding Copies the data from Source file to destination file**.
**PROBLEM:: why does Close() method not able to close the Opened file.?**
i m a beginner and keen to learn programming. THK IN ADV!!

Comment: You are closing FileOutputStream not File...

Comment: `Close()` is to close the resource, `FileOutputStream` in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here (a debugger would confirm this)

```
        do{
            i=fin.read();
            if(i!=-1) fout.write(i);

        }while(i!=1); // you are checking for 1 not -1.
```

I suggest you change this to

```
for (int b; (b = fin.read()) != -1;)
     fout.write(b);
```

or you can use a buffer

```
try (FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(args[0]);
     FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream(args[1])) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
    for (int len; (len = fin.read(bytes)) > 0; )
        fout.write(bytes, 0, len);
} // try-with-resource will close the files.
```

Comment: Other than the infinite loop, I think OP wants to copy the contents of `fin` to `fout`, not write the int result of reading the file.

Comment: @cricket_007 the int result of reading the file is the next byte (unless it is -1) so writing it will copy the file.

Comment: Ah, I see. I normally just do readline, but byte by byte works too.

Comment: @cricket_007 very slowly.... which is why you wouldn't normal do this, but it works.

Comment: i have another doubt .why are we using Throw IOException just below public static void main?

Comment: @Lalitkumar Do you mean `throws IOException`? You use that when the method can throw the checked exception `IOException`, which I suggest you do rather than adding your own error messages.